# How to limit depth of DIR /S?

Tags: batch-file

I'm doing a search for files and appending it to txt file and I want to limit the search in sub directories to one level down instead of multiple level sub directories.

My code looks like this at the moment.

```
set ProjectNo=12345
set ProjectLocation=E:\Projects\123 BSI\45 Bukit \G Model 12345\02 Models
set location=E:\Scripts

dir /S/B "%ProjectLocation%\\..\\%ProjectNo%-*-MDL-??-???.dwg" > %location%\%ProjectNo%-ML-%DATE%.txt
```

The list is long but a partial output is as follows:

> ```
> E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\GE\12345-30-MDL-GE-003.dwg
> E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ME\12345-25-MDL-ME-018.dwg
> E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ME\12345-30-MDL-ME-017.dwg
> E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ME\12345-25-MDL-ME-018\Details\12345-25-MDL-ME-018.dwg
> E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ME\_Superseded\12345-120-MDL-ME-018.dwg
> E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\PP\12345-25-MDL-PP-001.dwg
> E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ST\12345-01-MDL-ST-001.dwg
> E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ST\12345-01-MDL-ST-002.dwg
> ```

Any idea is to list only one level deep from `"E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\"`

The expected result is shown below:

```
E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\GE\12345-30-MDL-GG-003.dwg
E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ME\12345-25-MDL-KK-018.dwg
E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ME\12345-30-MDL-MM-017.dwg
E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\PP\12345-25-MDL-PP-001.dwg
E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ST\12345-01-MDL-SS-001.dwg
E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ST\12345-01-MDL-CC-002.dwg
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Directory names cannot end in a space: ``\45 Bukit \``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FOR /D` command to list all the directories in the root of your source directory.  Then use another `FOR` command to list the files you want in the single sub-directory of the source.

```
@echo off
set "ProjectNo=12345"
set "ProjectLocation=E:\Projects\123 BSI\45 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models"
set "location=E:\Scripts"

(FOR /D %%G IN ("%ProjectLocation%\*") DO (
    FOR %%H IN ("%%~G\%ProjectNo%-*-MDL-??-???.dwg") DO echo %%H
)
)>"%location%\%ProjectNo%-ML-%DATE%.txt"
```

All of the code changes I have done are best practices you should adhere to.  Quoting is optional but is required when there are spaces in paths.

In this scenario with the redirection the output file is only being opened once for writing.  If you did the redirect inside the `FOR` command it would open and close the file each time the `ECHO` command executes.

Comment: Hi Squashman,

Thank you for the quick reply.

The output I'm getting is as shown below:

E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\PP
E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ST
E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ST

As mention in the post, the idea is to get an output like this:
E:\Projects\123 BSI\04 Bukit\G Model 12345\02 Models\ST\12345-01-MDL-CC-002.dwg

Comment: Squashman, please edit your code. The second FOR instead of  "Do echo %%~G" should be "DO echo %%H" to get the output as I need it. After the editing I will mark you answer as the correct one! Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: I can't recall if new members have the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55364302/edit) button or not.  You can always suggest an edit.  I think you get  badge for that if I approve it.

Comment: I had to add text 6 characters minimum, but you are right about the edit! thanks again!